# Did David Hamelech reference his mother's name in Tehillim?

Tags: tanach, tehilim-psalms

I'm pretty sure I heard this at Shul:
Someone asked R' Zilberstein if he's allowed to publicly praise his living mother, if she doesn't want to be honored. So I think R' Zilvberstein answered that David Hamelech's mother didn't want to be mentioned in Tehillim. So David Hamelech followed her request, and only wrote a remez (hint) to her name.

I think but I don't remember for sure, that he said her name was נצבת Nitzevet. But I may be wrong.

(I don't have contact information for the Shul I davened for that minyan.)
Does anyone know where the remez in Tehillim is, and what her name is?

Thank you very much

Comment: http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/klli/mdrjim/em_dwd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is famously mentioned along with some other people’s mothers in the Talmud (Bava Basra 91a), including Avraham and Haman:

> אמיה דדוד נצבת בת עדאל שמה אמיה דשמשון צללפונית ואחתיה נשיין למאי נפקא מינה לתשובת המינים
>
> Rav Ḥanan bar Rava continues: The mother of David was named Natzvat bat Ada’el. The mother of Samson was named Tzelelponit, and his sister was called Nashyan. The Gemara asks: What is the practical difference as to what their names were? The Gemara answers: It is important with regard to an answer for heretics who inquire into the names of these women, which are not stated in the Bible. One can reply that there is a tradition handed down concerning their names (Sefaria Translation).

Comment: FWIW a quick search on Sefaria yields no results for any mention of נצבת in Tehillim, so whatever the remez is, it’s not just changing the vowels. However, I did notice that Chanah refers to herself as the אשה הנצבת (Shmuel 1:1:26), so perhaps there’s a connection there, between Shmuel’s mother and David’s.

Comment: @DonielF נצבת בת עדאל = נצב בעדת אל (Double AA posted [this link](http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/klli/mdrjim/em_dwd.html))

Comment: thank you to Double AA and Dr Shmuel